# Travis CI failed to install Go

Tags: go, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI, on commit is it is not building the module as expected and giving the following error:

```
0.52s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/kadnan/gkeevee.git kadnan/gkeevee
$ travis_export_go 1.14 github.com/kadnan/gkeevee
0.01s
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export GO111MODULE=on
$ export GOFLAGS='-mod vendor'
150.68s$ travis_setup_go
I don't have any idea what to do with '1.14'.
  (using download type 'auto')
Failed to run gimme
The command "travis_setup_go" failed and exited with 86 during .
```

Below is my `travis.yml`:

```
language: go

env: GO111MODULE=on GOFLAGS='-mod vendor'

go:
    1.14

install: true

notifications:
    email: false

script:
    - go test -v
```

Comment: Can you use `GIMME_DEBUG=1` to view more details ?

Comment: There is version related bug https://travis-ci.com/github/batazor/shortlink/builds/133099490

Comment: @Eklavya pls check this: https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/680110976/log.txt